# Получить текст вне html тэгов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Есть задача достать текст, который находится вне html тэгов.
Например: `'<strong>Hello, <em>World!</em></strong> 1 + 2 < 4!'`, из этой строки должна получиться строка: `' 1 + 2 < 4!'`. Или, если строка вообще без тэгов, то она же и должна вернуться.

Пробовол вот так вот: `([\s\S]+)(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)/gi`, но почему-то не работает (не могу понять почему, он просто возвращает всю строку). Пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: Попробуйте через `regexp.exec(str)` с флагом `g` найти все шаблоны `/<.+?>/`. По вот [этому примеру](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) ориентируйтесь. Так найдете все теги в строке. Потом найдите первый и последний индекс тегов. Затем сделайте срез заданной строки, исключив подстроку длинной от первого индекса первого тега до последнего индекса последнего тега. Надеюсь, что понятно объяснил.